# What is the ^s symbol in C?

Tags: c, io, text-parsing

I am trying to write a set of double values to a file. I am specifying the file to be a "name".dat extension. I successfully write the values I want, however a symbol that I have never seen before, nor can find online, is written.

Here is all I am writing:

```
fprintf(filePath,"%lg,%lg,%lg\n",struct[i].x,struct[i].y,struct[i].z);
```

Here is an example of some lines in my file when viewed through a text editor:

```
double,double,^Sdouble
double,double,^Sdouble
double,double,^Sdouble
```

and so on .....

The same **^S** symbol appears before the third set of data on every line. Can anyone explain what this symbol means? I am viewing this file through emacs. It may help with some parsing issues I am having.

Thank you for your consideration and help.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I don't think that is necessary. This is a simple question of "Have you seen this symbol before, and what does it mean?". I am not asking for code help.

Comment: Yet it is, because your code makes no sense.

Comment: @Bdubbx1 Respondents will need to know how your code written to the file.

Comment: Or at the very least, tell is how you are seeing the contents of the file: what OS are you using, are you typing the file to the console, opening it with an editor, etc.? Better though to just show the code.

Comment: The "code" appears in your output file because *you are writing it*. From the little context shown, it is not clear whether it is a single character display as `^S`, or *two* characters. Anyway, it does not matter which one it is; if you are surprised to find it in your output, your program must be doing something wrong. Hence: show the relevant part of your code.

Answer (score 1):

You are viewing your file with an editor which shows control characters:

```
# echo -ne "\x13" | cat -e
^S
```

How it got there no one is going to be able to tell you without seeing code.

Comment: is this a character that can be parsed?

Comment: A character is a character. Whether it can be "parsed" is dependent on what you are parsing it with, and you haven't told us that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what tool you are using to view the text file but I suspect a Unix environment, so maybe the `less` command.

The `less` command will convert control characters into ^S like that, using the ^ as a marker for the Control key. So you might see Control-C written as ^C for example.

If you want to make sure what the bytes in your text file really are you can use the `od` or `xxd` programs to view the file as byte numbers. Read the man page on each one.

I suspect that character is getting into your file because you are using either an unset variable, or a string pointer that is pointing to an illegal location.

Comment: I am viewing the file through emacs, I added that later for clarity. Your answer gives me an idea on what I need to look for, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

This is the ctrl S code

On some *nix systems, when you see a ^character, it means usually ctrl + character